# Wordpress email could not be sent

Tags: email, wp-mail

I have faced an error while forgetting email password in WordPress

link : `/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword`

After submitting email faced below errors:

```
ERROR: The email could not be sent. Your site may not be correctly configured to send emails.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common reason for this is that your WordPress hosting server is not configured to use PHP mail() function.

[How to configure your mail with wordpress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-not-sending-email-issue/) and [here is smtp plugin link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)